# Does putting everything in one SASS file violate the style guides?

Tags: css

I'm not a fan of having a lot of files in my project. I use vim and it's a lot easier to have all my stuff in one place rather than jumping between files.

However as I understand, it is preferred to separate things in SASS: variables, mixins, functions, forms, etc.

Should I do that as well, or is it "okay" to continue using one big file. I'm asking because I don't want to confuse developers/designers working on my stuff in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does putting everything in one SASS file violate the style guides?

I'm going to assume that, by *style guide*, you mean "best practices"? (Let me know if this is an incorrect assumption).
Whether or not stylesheets should be in single file or not is more a matter of opinion and from a technical perspective there wouldn't be a "violation".

I would say that If a project is small a single stylesheet file would generally be considered to be ok, but once the project gets bigger, then My experience is that most developers tend to separate blocks of SASS/LESS/CSS etc into separate files.
The bigger the project the more files.

Personally I use vim everyday and I still prefer to split My LESS stylesheets out into multiple files and use vims tab function to switch between files

- `:tabnew` - create new tab
- `ctrl + <pg or pg>` - to cycle between tabs

As, Im sure you know.

Also, if you want to know what other developers preference's are, I would take a look "out in the wild" at open source projects.
(You would want to see pre-compiled stylesheets as obviously production websites will typically deploy CSS in a different state to when in development).

As an example here are stylesheets of a couple of projects purely picked at random, one has many stylesheets (fancy design) the other actually has many stylesheets they just happen to be scattered about the project.

- [Simple Invoices - PHP invoicing app](https://github.com/simpleinvoices/simpleinvoices/blob/master/templates/default/css/main.css)
- [Coderwall website github project](https://github.com/assemblymade/coderwall/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, you are right: "best practices" is a better term for my question. Indeed, all open source projects are using multiple files, so I decided to adapt to that. And it does make sense as your project grows.